# The same mysql-connector-java package executes the same code with different effects

Tags: java, mysql, debugging

When I was using screw to export the database table structure, I found that the same code had different table field structures in different projects.

1.Get table structure information through the following code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9BmA.png)
2.debug into
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgbvr.png)
3.The same code executes with different results
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoWT3.png)
other project different effects
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8rw3.png)
4.the same config
spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
5.Executed directly in mysql, the result is the same
6.Debug found that mysqlInput is different
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKLON.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxaGX.png)

All are mysql-connector-java packages
The packet variable is read from the mysqlInput variable. I judge that the problem is caused by different versions of mysql or different versions, but I can't find relevant evidence.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnfV3.png)